# Using Angular CLI to create a project gives errors

Tags: node.js, macos, angular-cli

I am getting the following error when trying to use **Angular CLI** on **Mac OS Sierra**:

`$ ng new my-app
Error: Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.
Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.`

I have tried the following approaches:

**Deleting NodeJS completely using the following commands:** ([as stated on this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x/11178106#11178106))

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}`

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp`

`sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules`

**Then re-install Angular CLI**

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

I have checked folder permissions and the information states that I have read/write access to the folder.

What else could be the problem here?

I now have the following versions:

- Angular CLI: 1.7.1
- Node: 8.9.4
- OS: darwin x64
- NPM: v5.6.0

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have solved the problem.

As well as doing all of the above. I noticed that a folder...

`/Users/my-user-name/node_modules`

... still existed. I did the following:

1. Repeated the "Uninstall NodeJS" steps as listed in my original post.
2. Deleted the `node_modules` folder found in `/Users/my-user-name/node_modules`
3. Re-installed Node via the download link on the [NodeJS website](https://nodejs.org/en/)
4. Re-installed Angular CLI `npm install -g @angular/cli`
5. Created a new project `ng new my-app`
6. Success!

Hopefully that helps anybody else who had similar issues.